# Equivalent in Snowflake SQL for T-SQL CROSS APPLY

Tags: sql, t-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with 4 columns: State, Pens, Pencils, Papers, with the last 3 showing binary values (1 or 0).

```
State  Pens   Pencils   Papers
NY     1      0         1
CA     1      1         1
TX     0      0         1
```

This below code works in T-SQL, but I am having issues with converting this to Snow SQL.

```
SELECT X.State, Result.Combination
FROM Dataset X
CROSS APPLY (SELECT 'Pens' AS Val WHERE X.Pens = 1 UNION ALL SELECT NULL) Pens
CROSS APPLY (SELECT 'Pencils' AS Val WHERE X.Pencils = 1 UNION ALL SELECT NULL) Pencils
CROSS APPLY (SELECT 'Papers' AS Val WHERE X.Papers = 1 UNION ALL SELECT NULL) Papers
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', Pens.Val, Pencils.Val, Papers.Val) AS Combination) Result
WHERE Result.Combination > ''
ORDER BY X.State, LEN(Result.Combination), Result.Combination
```

I am trying to return a list of all combinations of column names in Snow SQL, when the output for each of those column names equates to 1 (TRUE).

For example, the result table should show the following 3 rows for State NY:

```
State  Combination
NY     Pens
NY     Papers
NY     Pens, Papers
```

I tried CROSS JOIN LATERAL but it's throwing an error "Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated" and other methods such as breaking it down to CTEs didn't help either. Maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

The "invalid subquery" is due to the `UNION`. You might solve that with a `CASE`:

```sql
WITH Dataset AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
        ('NY', 1, 0, 1),
        ('CA', 1, 1, 1),
        ('TX', 0, 0, 1)) X(State,Pens,Pencils,Papers)
)
SELECT X.State, Result.Combination
FROM Dataset X,
    LATERAL (SELECT CASE X.Pens WHEN 1 THEN 'Pens' END Val) Pens,
    LATERAL (SELECT CASE X.Pencils WHEN 1 THEN 'Pencils' END Val) Pencils,
    LATERAL (SELECT CASE X.Papers WHEN 1 THEN 'Papers' END Val) Papers,
    LATERAL (SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', Pens.Val, Pencils.Val, Papers.Val) AS Combination) Result
WHERE Result.Combination > ''
ORDER BY X.State, LEN(Result.Combination), Result.Combination
```

However you'll run into a second problem that `CONCAT_WS` behaves differently: for T-SQL it ignores `NULL`, for Snowflake any `NULL` will result in a `NULL` return. You'll only see CA.

My try would be to use `UNPIVOT` and `LISTAGG`:

```sql
WITH Dataset AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
        ('NY', 1, 0, 1),
        ('CA', 1, 1, 1),
        ('TX', 0, 0, 1)) X(State,Pens,Pencils,Papers)
)
SELECT State,LISTAGG(ItemType, ',') Items
FROM Dataset
    UNPIVOT(Item FOR ItemType IN (Pens, Pencils, Papers))
WHERE Item = 1
GROUP BY State
```

Comment: I tried UNPIVOT and LISTAGG. The issue is it's giving me only one aggregated row in the output instead of all possible combinations. For example, for NY, I am only seeing 'Pens, Papers' within that one row. I am trying to figure out a way to see 'Pens' and 'Papers' in separate rows as results, along with 'Pens, Papers'.

Comment: throw the UNPIVOT in a CTE and UNION a grouped and non-grouped SELECT from it.